# Importing customized module into renderer.js in Electron app

Tags: node.js, electron

I have a customized module that carries some functions that I would like to use in `renderer.js`. I tried the following ways of importing but it does not work (in fact, it causes some of the other functions in `renderer.js` to not execute as well.

`const supp = require('./supp.js')`

`const supp = require('./supp')`

`const supp = require('supp.js')`

`const supp = require(path.join(__dirname, '/supp.js')`

`import 'supp'`

`supp.js` sits in the same folder level as `renderer.js` and `main.js`. If someone could advise? Thanks.

Update: below is all the code in file `supp.js`

```
const pinOneInGrp = (itemID, grpName, itemColor, grpColor) => {
  let item = document.getElementById(itemID);
  let grpItems = document.getElementsByClassName(grpName);
  for(var i = 0; i < grpItems.length;i++) {
    grpItems[i].style.background-color = grpColor
  }
  item.style.background-color = itemColor;
}

module.exports = {
  pinOneInGrp
}
```

If one of the *import* or *require* lines above is included at the top of `renderer.js`, none of the subsequent actions in `renderer.js` is executed. For example, there is a `ipc.send()` and `ipc.on()` action right after the `import` / `require` line. These two do not send (and hence, receive back) from the `main.js`.

Comment: That the renderer simply stops running JS is an indication of an error in the imported file. Have you got any error message in the `BrowserWindow`'s DevTools console or in your app's `stdout`? We can't help you just off of "it doesn't work" -- there could be a million reasons why. Please [edit] your question accordingly to include any related information you've got.

Comment: @AlexanderLeithner I have added more details to the question. Basically, my ```supp.js``` is meant to contain frequently used functions that I don't want to fully repeat many times in ```renderer.js```. I want to implement them generic enough to be called in ```renderer.js``` many times by passing appropriate arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you've posted contains a typo. The error it's throwing (which you most probably can't see) is a `SyntaxError`, because you cannot subtract `color` (which is `undefined`) from `grpItems[i].style.background` and then assign to it. Thus, you simply have to correct your for-loo from

```js
for (var i = 0; i < grpItems.length; i++) {
    grpItems[i].style.background-color = grpColor;
}
```

to

```js
for (var i = 0; i < grpItems.length; i++) {
    grpItems[i].style.backgroundColor = grpColor;
}
```

(And the same goes for the style assignment right below the for-loop!)

Note that all CSS properties which are spelt with a hyphen when in a stylesheet must use camelCase as they otherwise would denote a subtraction, which is causing your problems. Also, this behaviour is explained in [Mozilla's Developer Network Web API reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ElementCSSInlineStyle/style), specifically under "Setting styles".

Comment: Thanks very much. It works now. This has driven me nut for the whole day.